# auto-py-to-exe problem with "module 'eel.chrome'"

Tags: python, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I want to convert my script to an exe but after installing auto-py-to-exe with -pip install auto-py-to-exe and executing auto-py-to-exe i get  following message:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "c:users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code<code, main_globals, None, File"c:users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code exec<code, run_globals> File "C:Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe\_main_.py", line 7, in <module> File "c:users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\auto-py-to_exe\_main_.py" , line 291, in run 
if eel.chrome.get_instance_path() is not None and not disable_chrome: AttributeError: module 'eel.chrome' has no attribute 'get_instance_path'
```

I tried reinstalling eel but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is already opened in GitHub as an issue [#275](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues/275).

According to the author of the program,

> brentvollebregt commented:
>
> It looks like this was maybe fixed in 2.6.6.